# gulp watch not watching imported less files

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

i'm using Laravel 5.1, which ships with `laravel elixir` - a wrapper for `gulp`.

My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less');
});
```

And `app.less` looks like this:

```
@import "../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "variables";
```

I'm running `gulp watch` from the command line, but the problem is that it only reacts when changes are made to `app.less` and not the imported files (e.g. `bootstrap.less`).

How can I enable `gulp watch` to watch imported files also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that because `../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less` is above the root folder being watched, then it is not watched, despite it being included.

`gulp watch` watches all assets in the folder, it doesn't read the less files for includes.